# OpenCV C++: DFT Bandpass Filtered Image Showing Reduced Intensity

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, filtering, fft

I am trying to design a bandpass filter to remove some low frequency components and high frequency noise from the inpout image:

[image: input_image]

I want to get rid of the large darker spot on the left side of the image, the bright row by row information is useful and should be kept after the filtering.

This is the filtered image:

[image: filtered_image]

The filter seems to have removed the dark spot, but the problem is that the intensity of the bright pixels obviously has been reduced which is not what I want, I want to keep the contrast between the bright rows and the dark background.

I have not much experience with image filtering in frequency domain. I don't know whether this result is normal when low-frequency signal has been removed? The code snippet has been attached.

```
void fft_filtering(cv::Mat img_gray, cv::Mat img_alpha) {
    int M = GetOptimalDftSize(img_gray.rows);
    int N = GetOptimalDftSize(img_gray.cols);
    cv::Mat img_gray_padded;
    cv::Mat planes[2];
    cv::copyMakeBorder(img_gray, img_gray_padded, 0, M - img_gray.rows, 0,
            N - img_gray.cols, cv::BORDER_CONSTANT, cv::Scalar::all(0));
    planes[0] = cv::Mat_<float>(img_gray_padded);
    planes[1] = cv::Mat::zeros(img_gray_padded.size(), CV_32F);
    cv::Mat img_complex;
    cv::merge(planes, 2, img_complex);
    cv::dft(img_complex, img_complex);

    cv::Mat filter(img_complex.size(), CV_32F);
    int f3_inpixel, f2_inpixel, f1_inpixel;
    CreateGaussianFilter(filter, img_alpha, FilterType::kBandPass, f3_inpixel, f2_inpixel, f1_inpixel);

    // Apply filter
    shiftDFT(img_complex);
    cv::mulSpectrums(img_complex, filter, img_complex, 0);
    shiftDFT(img_complex);

    // Do inverse DFT on the filtered image
    cv::idft(img_complex, img_complex);
    // Split into planes and extract plane 0 as output image
    cv::split(img_complex, planes);
    cv::Mat img_out;
    cv::normalize(planes[0], img_out, 0, 1, CV_MINMAX);
    cv::Rect img_roi(0, 0, img_gray.cols, img_gray.rows);
    img_filtered = img_out(img_roi); 
}

void CreateGaussianFilter(cv::Mat& filter, cv::Mat img_alpha, FilterType filter_type,
        float cutoff_f_low_InPixels, float cutoff_f_high_InPixels, float cutoff_f_center_InPixels){
    cv::Mat gf(filter.size(), CV_32F);
    cv::Point centre(filter.cols / 2, filter.rows / 2);
    for(int u = 0; u < gf.rows; u++) {
        for(int v = 0; v < gf.cols; v++) {
            switch (filter_type) {
            case FilterType::kHighPass:
                gf.at<float>(u, v) = 1- GaussianCoeff(u - centre.y, v - centre.x, cutoff_f_low_InPixels);
                break;
            case FilterType::kLowPass:
                gf.at<float>(u, v) = GaussianCoeff(u - centre.y, v - centre.x, cutoff_f_high_InPixels);
                break;
            case FilterType::kBandPass:
                gf.at<float>(u, v) = GaussianCoeff(u - centre.y, v - centre.x, cutoff_f_high_InPixels) -
                GaussianCoeff(u - centre.y, v - centre.x, cutoff_f_low_InPixels);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    // Keep the center pixel
    gf.at<float>(centre.y, centre.x) = 1.0;

    cv::Mat toMerge[] = {gf, gf};
    merge(toMerge, 2, filter);
}
```

Comment: Switch the normalization and cropping — crop first, normalize after. The normalization is the only thing in your code that affects the contrast, any other effect is neutralized by the normalization.

Comment: Thanks@CrisLuengo, tried, seems not the reason, result did not change